# Can you identify this caterpillar?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, taxonomy

Hi on my walk home in may i found this larvae crawling on a small road between grass and fields. All the yellowish larvae i know are looking totally differend than this. The origin of this picture is in the middle of Germany. The larva is is around 5 cm long and 1 cm tall.

[image]

Thank you